# inner join two foreign key in one table

Tags: mysql

i have query sql for searching. i have two table to be inner join. this my table :

```html
table_order
------------
id_order  id_user_order  id_user_taker  status
1          2              3              done
2          2              4              done

table_user
--------------
id_user    name
1          Alex
2          Jason
3          Danis
4          Lorent
```

i will inner join like this :

```html
<?php
include'conn.php'
$qry = $conn->query("select table_order.*, table_user.name AS order_name, table_user.name AS taker_name FROM table_order INNER JOIN table_user ON table_user.id_user = table_order.id_user_order INNER JOIN table_user ON table_user.id_user = table_order.id_user_taker ");

while($data = $qry->fetch_assoc()){
echo $data['order_name'] . " " . $data['taker_name'];
}

?>
```

but, cannot show. Please solve my problem guys. thanks so much

Comment: can you be more specific ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you need  join the same table two or more time you must use a proper alias for the tables

```
 $qry = $conn->query("select 
              table_order.*
            , a.name AS order_name
            , b.name AS taker_name 
            FROM table_order 
            INNER JOIN table_user as a ON a.id_user = table_order.id_user_order 
            INNER JOIN table_user as b ON b.id_user = table_order.id_user_taker ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use alias for your table name if you want to use the same table more then once in a query:

```
$qry = $conn->query("select table_order.*, table_user_o.name AS order_name, table_user_t.name AS taker_name 
FROM table_order INNER JOIN table_user table_user_o ON table_user_o.id_user = table_order.id_user_order 
        INNER JOIN table_user table_user_t ON table_user_t.id_user = table_order.id_user_taker");
```

Answer (score 0):

some changes in query

```
   select table_order.*, table_user.name AS order_name, table_user.name AS taker_name FROM 
            table_user 
            INNER JOIN table_order ON   table_order.id_user_order = table_user.id_user
            INNER JOIN table_order ON   table_order.id_user_taker = table_user.id_user
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you require names of users for order and taker along with the fields in table_order. If that is the case, then you need to use 'LEFT JOIN'.

```
    select too.*, tuo.name AS order_name, tut.name AS taker_name FROM table_order too left join table_user tuo on tuo.id_user=too.id_user_order left join table_user tut on tut.id_user=too.id_user_taker
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query

```
select table_order.*, user.name FROM table_user user
        INNER JOIN table_order  ON   table_order.id_user_order = user.id_user
        where  table_order.id_order=1
```